# Come definire siti che appartengono allo stesso gruppo

Tags: word-usage

In inglese si usa spesso l'espressione "sister site" quando ci si riferisce ad un sito che appartiene allo stesso gruppo.

Ad esempio SE Italian e SE Spanish sono "sister sites" in quanto appartengono allo stesso gruppo. (StackExchange).

Quale è la definizione che si usa in italiano per definire la relazione tra due siti  della stessa famiglia?

Espressioni come  "sito sorella o sito fratello" non sono presenti in internet, mentre  "[sito gemello](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22sito%20internet%20gemello%22)" in effetti viene usato,  ma non sono sicuro che  sia la definizione corretta.

Comment: Perché non *sito fratello*? A me non suona così male. Non credo che esista un termine "ufficiale" per cui tanto vale inventarlo

Answer (score 2):

Penso si potrebbe dire ***sito correlato*** oppure ***sito omologo***.
Nel caso che tu citi SEItalian è appunto l'omologo Italiano del sito SESpanish, in quanto ha lo stesso ruolo o meglio missione del sito in spagnolo.

Da [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/omologo/) per il termine omologo si legge:

> In genere, che corrisponde a un altro, che è della stessa specie, o ha
>   le stesse qualità, proprietà, ecc. di un altro

Sono anche forniti significati particolari relativi a chimica, matematica, zoologia, botanica, medicina etc. che riconducono comunque ad un concetto di similitudine, appartenenza ad una stessa classificazione o gruppo.

Nell'ambito informatico, per estensione, il significato è sempre quello di essere un sito simile, vuoi nell'aspetto vuoi nelle funzionalità, ad un altro e di conseguenza essere raggruppato o classificato in un determinato modo.

Comment: Non sono sicuro che lo capirei, senza una spiegazione...

Comment: “Omologo” è un concetto diverso da quello che chiede l'OP: come da definizione che citi, si riferisce a qualcosa che corrisponde a qualcos'altro e ne ha le stesse proprietà, ma in un altro ambito. Per esempio, si dice che il ministro degli esteri del paese X è l'omologo di quello del paese Y. Invece, nella similitudine dei ministri, l'OP sta chiedendo un termine per designare due ministri dello stesso governo.

Answer (score 1):

Cercando in rete:

[**Qui**](http://www.linguee.it/inglese-italiano/traduzione/sister+site.html)

> [...] several Ancestry.com websites (including international sites
>   such as Ancestry.co.uk as well as our sister site, Mundia.com).
>   ancestry.com
>
> [...] siti web di Ancestry (compresi i siti
>   internazionali come Ancestry.co.uk così come il nostro sito gemello,
>   Mundia.com).

e [**qui**](https://translate.google.com/#en/it/sister%20website)

Viene adoperato il termine `sito gemello`

In gergo informatico, personalmente uso anche io questo termine, invece di esplicitare la parentela (nel qual caso in italiano sarebbe `fratello`, in quanto sito è maschile)

Comment: Si, mi è capitato di leggere sito gemello, ma mai sito fratello.

Comment: Si è davvero poco usuale "fratello" magari è anche corretto ma non lo userei

Comment: “Gemello” fa pensare a un sito “uguale”, cioè con caratteristiche uguali o similissimi, gli stessi argomenti, gli stessi fini etc., non a siti magari molto diversi ma dello stesso gruppo, come chiede l'OP.

Comment: Come @DaG, troverei molto ambiguo chiamare "gemello" un sito che è soltanto simile o correlato a un altro.

Comment: Allora forse è errato chiamarli anche sister site in inglese?

Comment: altrimenti che ne pensate se si usasse il termine "siti cugini"?

Comment: @JoeTaras - concordo, ecco come la pensano loro a riguardo..le idee rimangono poco chiare in ogni caso: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/369932/usage-and-origin-of-sister-in-expressions-like-sister-company-sister-ship-s

Comment: In onor del vero ritengo che "sito gemello" derivi dal più comune "gemellaggio" tra città. Forse la dicitura migliore sarebbe "sito gemellato" in quanto presenta molte cose in comune, nonostante siano estremamente differenti.

Comment: Ad onor del vero....

Comment: @Fylax: Sito gemellato per me è un sito che effettua uno scambio di link

Comment: @Gio: Si in effetti nella discussione che hai postato il termine sister abbraccia diverse connotazioni. Probabilmente nella nostra lingua, bisogna contestualizzare e trovare di volta in volta il giusto termine.

Answer (score 1):

Mi sono posto diverse volte questo problema per il lavoro che faccio e l'unica soluzione che ho trovato per indicare siti dello stesso gruppo è dire appunto *siti dello stesso gruppo* oppure, ma suona un po' buffo, *siti imparentati*.

Sembra che sia uno di quei casi dove un'espressione semplice in inglese non è entrata in uso in italiano anche se avrebbe una traduzione ovvia.

Comment: Finirà che useremo anche noi l'espressione "sister site" anche in italiano... inglesismo più, inglesismo meno...